# unable to parse String-Date to java.time.LocalDateTime with specific format

Tags: java, java-time

Following code prints output with Date in String with timeZone offset.

```
String BERLIN_TIME_ZONE = "Europe/Berlin";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ");
String dateTimeInString = formatter
        .format(ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.now(), ZoneId.of(BERLIN_TIME_ZONE)));

System.out.println(dateTimeInString); // 2021-06-07T02:12:08+0200
```

This works perfectly fine. Now, at this point when we have `dateTimeInString` so I want to convert it back to `LocalDateTime` object by using `parse` method.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ");
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeInString,formatter));
```

but this parsing is throwing an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-06-07T02:12:08+0200' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {SecondOfMinute=8, MinuteOfHour=12, HourOfAmPm=2, OffsetSeconds=7200, NanoOfSecond=0, MilliOfSecond=0, MicroOfSecond=0},ISO resolved to 2021-06-07 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:2017)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1952)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at de.finhome.A.main(A.java:19)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {SecondOfMinute=8, MinuteOfHour=12, HourOfAmPm=2, OffsetSeconds=7200, NanoOfSecond=0, MilliOfSecond=0, MicroOfSecond=0},ISO resolved to 2021-06-07 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.java:461)
    at java.base/java.time.format.Parsed.query(Parsed.java:235)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor: {SecondOfMinute=8, MinuteOfHour=12, HourOfAmPm=2, OffsetSeconds=7200, NanoOfSecond=0, MilliOfSecond=0, MicroOfSecond=0},ISO resolved to 2021-06-07 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.base/java.time.LocalTime.from(LocalTime.java:431)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.java:457)
    ... 4 more
```

I have check different resources but couldn't figure out the issue.

Comment: A `LocalDateTime` cannot store any time zone or offset, even if the pattern of the formatter used is correct. You have to parse a `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` and call `toLocalDateTime()` on the result.

Comment: @deHaar No, that's not the issue.

Comment: @deHaar No, `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` will not resolve the issue as their parsing will be failed as well.

Comment: @Freak yes, just seen that ;-) You need another way...

Comment: @Michael yes, that's not what causes the exception, but it's an issue, too, as far as I understand OP... OP wants a `LocalDateTime` to output an offset and that's not possible, is it?

Comment: @deHaar ZonedDateTime is convertible to LocalDateTime, all you need to do is throw away the zone. When parsing, even if the string contains a zone, as OP's does, the formatter can parse that into a LocalDateTime no problem. Basically, a parser is not required to use every piece of information. You can parse a string containing date and time into just a LocalTime if you want. The parser just ignores the stuff it doesn't care about. Same principal

Comment: @deHaar Yes, Correct !!

Comment: @Michael Sure, I know, but thanks for posting that anyway. Couldn't OP just go the other way round, like use `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of(BERLIN_TIME_ZONE))` and output a `format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATETIME)` omitting the zone but leaving the offset? Looks like (near to) what OP wants.

Comment: @deHaar Honestly, besides avoiding the exception which I explained in my answer, I have no idea what OP wants it to do. The question includes an exception and I explained why it was thrown and how to resolve it. If there are additional requirements besides "don't crash", they need to be listed more precisely.

Answer (score 2):

Change the hour token from `hh` to `HH`. Lowercase `h` is 0-12, or what [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) call *clock-hour-of-am-pm*. Uppercase `H` is 0-23, or what the docs call *hour-of-day*.

While the formatter can oblige quite happily when outputting the date, when you try to read in the same string it creates an ambiguity. The parser doesn't know whether `...T01:...` is supposed to be 1AM or PM. Since it cannot parse unambiguously, it fails.

Alternatively, add something into your format string for AM/PM (you can use `a` for that). Then the parser will be able to unambiguously interpret an hour such as 01.

Seems you also want to change `LocalDateTime.parse` to `ZonedDateTime.parse` so you're not throwing away the zone.

Comment: but this won't give me my desired output which is `2021-06-07T14:34:13+0200` as soon as we convert it to `LocalDateTime`, it will discard the `offset` and will be printed like this `2021-06-07T14:34:13`

Comment: But Yes, I agree that it will resolve the exception and would work fine.

Comment: @Freak I don't follow. Your current code will represent 2PM (14) as 02. If you want it to be 14, you need to use `HH`, not `hh`

Comment: @Micheal The String I am sending as an argument to `parse` method is with offset `2021-06-07T14:34:13+0200` mean `+0200` in the end but after calling `LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime,formatter)` it prints `2021-06-07T14:41:55` in which offset is missing.

Comment: @Freak The string in your example given in the question is `2021-06-07T02:12:08+0200`. In the example in your question, you read **back in** a string that the same formatter outputs. There is no way that formatter can **output** `...T14:...` If the example does not represent your actual problem, please change it.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion !! Actually this code has two propblems. The one which you have mentioned with `hh` and `24h` issue which is correct But I didn't have my attention there but thanks for mentioning it. The real issue is that when I am having a String with `offset` , it is not convertible to `LocalDatetime` and offset get removed.

Comment: @Freak No problem. I added a line at the bottom of my answer. I think that solves the 2nd problem

Comment: +1 for the hint but this will return back `ZonedDateTime`. I guess the above comment from @deHaar is correct that `LocaldateTime` doesn't save the `offset` where all this confusion lies.

Comment: @Freak I guess I fundamentally don't understand the issue. Your question asked why you got the exception, and I've explained it and how to fix it. Your question mentions nowhere that "The output doesn't contain a timezone" -- and of course it couldn't have because it was crashing before it output anything. Now I explain how to add the timezone to the output and for some reason that's not what you want either. I think you need to revisit your question and list very precisely the exact output you are getting and the exact output you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

This does not look like a situation where one should use a `LocalDateTime`.

There are two alternatives: `ZonedDateTime` as you already use and `OffsetDateTime`, which you might want to use...

If you want to provide a zone, take the current moment in time in that zone and print the result without the explicit zone but with the offset of that zone, then I recommend to stick to a `ZonedDateTime` for most of the time.

Do something like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // provide a zone
    String BERLIN_TIME_ZONE = "Europe/Berlin";
    // use ZonedDateTime.now() directly and pass the zone
    ZonedDateTime nowBerlin = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of(BERLIN_TIME_ZONE));
    // then create a String that actually keeps the offset and omits the zone
    String dateTimeInString = nowBerlin.format(
                                DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME
                              );
    // print the result
    System.out.println(dateTimeInString);
    
    // if you now want to convert back, use an OffsetDateTime
    OffsetDateTime nowPlus2h = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTimeInString);
    // and print the result
    System.out.println(nowPlus2h.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
    // if you want it to not just be a time of 2 hours offset, apply the zone again
    ZonedDateTime nowAgainBerlin = nowPlus2h.atZoneSameInstant(
                                        ZoneId.of(BERLIN_TIME_ZONE)
                                    );
    // check if that's the same as parsed in the beginning
    if (nowAgainBerlin.equals(nowBerlin)) {
        System.out.println("Same instant in Berlin");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong in Berlin");
    }
    
    // and if you really want to get a LocalDateTime, you can get it like this
    LocalDateTime localBerlin = nowBerlin.toLocalDateTime();
    LocalDateTime localAgainBerlin = nowPlus2h.toLocalDateTime();
    
    System.out.println(localBerlin + " == " + localAgainBerlin);
}
```

This just output

```
2021-06-07T15:16:47.259+02:00
2021-06-07T15:16:47.259+02:00
Same instant in Berlin
2021-06-07T15:16:47.259 == 2021-06-07T15:16:47.259
```

If you want to not have millis in your output, then define a formatter that suits your desires, but still, you won't be able to parse zones or offsets to a `LocalDateTime`.